# С. Алгебраическая проблема

Tags: c, олимпиада

Даны числа d — степень полинома, массив K—коэффициенты полинома P(x) и число а. Требуется найти и вывести коэффициенты произведения полинома P(x) на (x–a). 
Input 
Со стандартного устройства ввода в первой строке вводится целое число d (1 <= d <= 1000) степень полинома, во второй строке вводятся (d+1) целых чисел — массив K (-1000 <= Ki <= 1000)—коэффициенты при членах в полиноме от старшей степени к младшей. В третьей вводится число а (-1000 <= a <= 1000). 
 Output 
 Требуется найти и вывести коэффициенты произведения полинома P(x) на (x–a). Выводить пробел в конце строки не нужно.
Sample Input

```
2
2 0 3
-4
```

Sample Output

```
2 8 3 12
```

мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int d,k[1000],a,b[1000],i;
    scanf("%d", &d);
    for (i = 0; i <= d; i++)
    scanf("%d", &k[i]);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    b[0] = k[0];
    for (i = 1; i <= d + 1; i++) {
        if (i != d + 1) b[i] = k[i] - (k[i - 1] * a);
        else b[i] = 0 - (k[i - 1] * a);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= d + 1; i++)
        if (i != d + 1) printf("%d ", b[i]);
        else printf("%d", b[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Набирает 70 из 100. Что не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: На максимальной степени мимо массива обращение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё выглядит нормально, кроме того, что полином степени 1000 имеет 1001 коэффициент, а результат 1002

```
 k[1002],b[1002]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло)

Answer (score 1):

Выделять массив коэффициентов можно динамически, а массив `b` и не нужен совсем. Такой код проходит?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int d,a;
    scanf("%d", &d);
    int * k = malloc(sizeof(int)*(d+1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= d; i++) scanf("%d", k+i);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 0; i <= d + 1; i++) {
        int b;
        if (i == 0) b = k[0];
        else if (i == d+1) b = -a*k[d];
        else b = k[i] - a*k[i-1];
        printf("%d ", b);
        }
    free(k);
    }
```

Comment: Можно добавить фейковые коэффициенты в `k` в начало и в конец, и тогда вся эта `if`-логика оказывается излишней.

Comment: Нас просили именно 2 массива) Но я уже решил проблему. Спасибо огромное за ваш ответ.